# 'TypeError: $(...).typeIt is not a function' - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with my scripts on Wordpress.

I have enqueued scripts in my functions.php file:

```
function pg_theme_js() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'typeit_js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.typeit/4.3.0/typeit.min.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'functions_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'smoothscroll_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/smoothscroll.js', array('jquery', '', false));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'prefix_js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js', array('jquery'), '', false);

    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pg_theme_js' );
```

My TypeIt javascript code looks like this:

```
$('#typing-code').typeIt({
     strings: [
         '&lt;div class="container"&gt;', 
     ],
     speed: 40,
     autoStart: false,
    startDelay: 50,
    breakDelay: 50
});
```

And all my .js files are wrapped in this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //code
});
```

The problem seems to arise at the typeIt snippet and causes all the following code that comes after it to break too.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For reference if anyone needs help in the future:

For the enqueued scripts in functions.php, remove 'get_template_directory_uri()' for the scripts with a complete URL.